# Final Cut Pro 10.4 for macOS Mojave

Tags: mojave, video, compatibility, video-editing, final-cut-pro

If a user is running macOS Mojave 10.14.6 and does not want to upgrade to Catalina or Big Sur, how can they trial Final Cut Pro? The latest Final Cut Pro, [10.5.1. released in December 2020](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201237) in the App Store says that it requires macOS BigSur 10.15.6 or later. Running the [free trial download from Apple](https://www.apple.com/final-cut-pro/trial/) also requires macOS BigSur. [This thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252162942) mentions that one way to run Final Cut Pro on Mojave is to buy the product and then downgrade.

Some websites, such as [this one](https://allmacworld.com/final-cut-pro-10-4-9-free-download/), list previous versions of Final Cut Pro. This carries security risk such as [bundled malware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SourceForge#Project_hijackings_and_bundled_malware).

How can a macOS Mojave user try the latest compatible version of Final Cut Pro, presumably 10.4.10?

Comment: As a heavy Final Cut X user, I really recommend you don't use it. It is a clumsy software. If you are not willing to pay for Premiere subscription, get DaVince Resolve for free and be happy.

Comment: I agree with you now @MateusRibeiro. Unfortunately, I have legacy projects in Final Cut Pro that I want to tweak or export to Premiere.

Comment: Correct: Version 10.4.10 is the latest compatible version for Mojave 10.14.6